# What causes this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with a simple "for"?

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my array code? the output is correct, but there is some error showing at the bottom of the output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] number = {1,2,3,4,5};

    System.out.println("Number in ascending order: ");
    for (int x=0; x < number.length; ++x)
        System.out.println(number[x]);

    lasttofirst(number);

}

public static void lasttofirst(int[] number)
{
    System.out.println("Number in descending order: ");
    for (int x=4; x<number.length; --x)
        System.out.println(number [x]+ " ");
}
```

Comment: the error is:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at lab011211.IntArray.lasttofirst(IntArray.java:25)
 at lab011211.IntArray.main(IntArray.java:17)

Comment: And the answer to the updated title is: you do :) `number[outofbounds]` :(

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in following logic

```
for (int x=4; x<number.length; --x)
```

when initially x= 4 it is satisfying condition `x<number.length` because 4<5
then x value becomes 3 for next occurance 3<5 also satisfys
...
..
when x value becomes 0 then 0*Problem occured Now x value became -1* then -1number[-1] gives you *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* The array contains data **from 0th posiiton to number of element -1 position**

Instead of that logic you can use following logic

```
for (int x=number.length-1; x>=0; --x)
            System.out.println("Index..."+x+"..."+number [x]+ " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error here:

```
for (int x=4; x<number.length; --x)
```

`x<number.length` should read `x >= 0`.

Comment: In the long term, you don't help people by doing their homework for them.

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly typed your `for` loop

If you want to print table elements in backwards, you have to start from last (so, length - 1, cause we index from 0), until `x` is less than 0.

so it should be:

```
for(int i=number.length-1; x>=0; --x){
   System.out.println(number[x]); // <-- also you dont need +" ", as printLN inserts new line
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I dont know really understand what you are trying to achieve with your

```
lastoffirst(number)
```

But your problem lies here-

```
for (int x=4; x<number.length; --x)
```

I can see that the value of number.length is 5 and you are decereasing your loop variable starting from a number smaller than 5. ultimatele at one stage it tries to print number [-1] which is not possible. thats why you are getting that error.

Cheers.